# How do I add a table row with this jquery script?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I have a script that converts a select list into a table of checkboxes;

```
$('#edit-taxonomy-1').parent().append('<table id="checkboxes"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');

$('#edit-taxonomy-1 option').each(function() {
    var label = $(this).html();
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    if (ind % 3 === 0  ) {
        $('#checkboxes tbody').append('</tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;+value+&#039;">' + label + '</td>');
    }
    else {
        $('#checkboxes tbody').append('<td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;+value+&#039;">' + label + '</td>');
    }
});

$('#edit-taxonomy-1').replaceWith($("#checkboxes"));
```

However I cannot get every third element to show up in a new row nicely.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/

It shows what I have and what I want

Comment: In case you didn't get the comment warning here's how I would have done it: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quick and just working update without refactoring the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/22/
Edit: The tr inside the table declaration is not needed. Replace it with

```
$('#edit-taxonomy-1').parent().append('<table id="checkboxes"><tbody></tbody></table>');
```

updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/34/

Comment: I dig this answer the most. Nice use of `:last` and more logical. +1

Comment: be sure to still remove the extra empty TR at the beginning

Answer (score 4):

I think `append()` is doing things behind the scenes that might be "fixing" your html for you before it appends it.

Try this similar approach:

```
var tr = "";
$('#edit-taxonomy-1 option').each(function() {
    var label = $(this).html();
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var ind = $(this).index() + 1;

    // continually build your checkbox and label
    var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" value="&#039;' + value + '&#039;" />' 
        + label;

    // keep adding to your tr
    tr += "<td>" + checkbox + "</td>";
    if (ind % 3 == 0) {
        // append the tr and clear its value
        $('#checkboxes tbody').append('<tr>' + tr + '</tr>');
        tr = "";
    }
});

// if ind % 3 was never hit above, output what is within tr
if (tr != "")
{
    $('#checkboxes tbody').append('<tr>' + tr + '</tr>');
}
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/18/

---

super updated solution:

```
$('#edit-taxonomy-1').parent().append('<table id="checkboxes"><tbody></tbody></table>');

$('#edit-taxonomy-1 option').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (index % 3 === 0  ) {
        $('#checkboxes tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
    }
    $('#checkboxes tbody tr:last').append('<td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;' + $this.val() + '&#039;" />' + $this.html()+ '</td>');
});

$('#edit-taxonomy-1').replaceWith($("#checkboxes"));
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/40/

Comment: this is the correct answer. I was doing the same thing in jsfiddle. Here was my solution... +1 for doing it faster than me :)  http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/24/

Comment: Yeah, you need to put valid HTML in there or the browser may do strange things to fix it. You have to think of the DOM as the DOM and not as HTML. (ie. You can't just throw opening and closing tags in there, you have to add elements to the parent element.) Here's my solution with jQuery and some other additions: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/27/

Comment: I thought so, too, until I saw suhairs answer, which is the most correct answer

Comment: @Drackir nice solution as well and even more elegant and straight forward

Comment: Thanks. :) There are actually a bunch of ways the OPs code could be improved but I suppose it's outside of the scope of the question. :P

Comment: @Ima check his jsfiddle link above

Comment: @Ima - Actually, I was thinking something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/38/ It's kind-of a hybrid between mine and hunter's.

Comment: @Drackir I like your 1st solution much better. Try this hybrid of all of the good ideas I've seen in this question: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/40/

Comment: I'm just saying, from an efficiency stand-point, that one will be faster than all of them. :) It may not be as elegant as some jQuery solutions, but it's faster.

Comment: @hunter I noticed that you didn't declare the `$(this).html` and  `$(this).attr('value')` as variables in the beginning. Is there some advantage to doing so?

Comment: @ima they were only used once so I didn't think it was necessary to declare the variable, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are appending a TD straight to the table body and not to a table row:

```
 $('#checkboxes tbody').append('<td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;+value+&#039;">' + label + '</td>');
```

EDIT:

```
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $('#edit-taxonomy-1 option').each(function() {
        var label = $(this).html();
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        var ind = $(this).index();
        if (ind % 3 === 0  ) {
            $('#checkboxes tbody').append(row);
            row = $('<tr></tr>');
            var td = $('<td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;+value+&#039;">' + label + '</td>');
            row.append(td);
        }
        else {
            $('<td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;+value+&#039;">' + label + '</td>').appendTo(row);
        }
    });
    if(row.html().length>0){
        $('#checkboxes tbody').append(row);
    }
```

Comment: yea i know but if I do `$('#checkboxes tbody tr')` it duplicates the entries

Answer (score 0):

The previous examples had extra TR's, so I thought you might want to see this solution. Good luck: http://jsfiddle.net/cxVhz/23/

Answer (score 0):

This JS works.

```
$('#edit-taxonomy-1 option').each(function() {
    var label = $(this).html();
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    if (ind % 3 === 0) {
        $('#checkboxes tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
    }
    $('#checkboxes tbody tr:last-child').append('<td><input type="checkbox" value="&#039;+value+&#039;">' + label + '</td>');
});
```